# Why two identical while loop behave differently

Tags: java, arithmetic-expressions

I have been struggling for hours and couldn't find reasonable explanation.
here is a code:

```
int num = 1;
while (num++ < 5); 
System.out.println(num); // Why num == 6 ??
```

So, the question is why num == 6 ?
I thought this code the same as below:

```
int num = 1;
while (num < 5) num++;
System.out.println(num); // num == 5
```

Comment: sorry if the question is super obvious

Comment: *"Why two identical while loop behave differently?"* - because they are not identical.  Obviously.

Comment: @Anarantt For cases like this where you find yourself spending hours, you could have used a debugger to look at the value of `num` step by step if you can't deduce its value by yourself manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `while` loop does not execute anything, save for incremending `num` - see the semi-colon right after the `while` statement.

Since the unary increment evaluates after the condition, `num++ < 5` will increment `num` until its value is `6`, because the termination condition is `num == 5`, and then `num` gets incremented one more time.

In your second example, `num` gets incremented **only** if the condition applies, hence one less time than your first example.

**Example 1**

- Assign `1` to `num`
- Iterate `num`: is `1 (increment later) < 5` ? Yes
- Iterate `num`: is `2 (increment later) < 5` ? Yes
- Iterate `num`: is `3 (increment later) < 5` ? Yes
- Iterate `num`: is `4 (increment later) < 5` ? Yes
- Iterate `num`: is `5 (increment later) < 5` ? No, stop
- At this point, `num` is still incremented by `1` hence `num == 6`

**Example 2**

- Assign `1` to `num`
- Iterate `num`: is `1 < 5` ? Yes, therefore increment `num`
- Iterate `num`: is `2 < 5` ? Yes, therefore increment `num`
- Iterate `num`: is `3 < 5` ? Yes, therefore increment `num`
- Iterate `num`: is `4 < 5` ? Yes, therefore increment `num`
- Iterate `num`: is `5 < 5` ? No, stop without incrementing
- Hence, `num == 5`

Answer (score 4):

```
int num = 1;
while (num++ < 5); 
System.out.println(num);
```

Here num is compared and incremented everytime. So for the last iteration num is incremented but condition fails. So the output is 6.

```
int num = 1;
while (num < 5) num++;
System.out.println(num);
```

Here you are comparing the num with 5 and incrementing num. For the last iteration condition fails and didn't increment the num. so the output is 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (num++ < 5);
```

- 1st check: 1 < 5 = true; After check: i = 2;
- 2nd check: 2 < 5 = true; After check: i = 3;
- 3rd check: 3 < 5 = true; After check: i = 4;
- 4th check: 4 < 5 = true; After check: i = 5;
- 5th check: 5 < 5 = false; After check: i = 6; Break the loop;

---

```
while (num < 5) num++;
```

- 1st check: 1 < 5 = true; After check: i = 2;
- 2nd check: 2 < 5 = true; After check: i = 3;
- 3rd check: 3 < 5 = true; After check: i = 4;
- 4th check: 4 < 5 = true; After check: i = 5;
- 5th check: 5 < 5 = false; Break the loop;

Answer (score 1):

Since `num++` is an *expression* with a value of the unincremented value of `num`, `while (num++ < 5);` will finish with `num` incremented 1 beyond 5.

With `while (num < 5) num++;`, the *statement* `num++;` will only be ran up to `num` being 4: the value of `num` after the statement is ran for the last time will be 5.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the comparison is done before the increment on num. So the steps from when `num` equals `5` look something like this:

```
num = 5
num < 5, so exit loop
num++
num = 6
print num
```

Had you used a pre-increment, like `while(++num < 5);` then `num` would have been `5` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because `while (num++ < 5);` will first compare the `num` with value and then will increment it. For Example, when `num -> 5` then `5 < 5` is false hence loop will terminate but `++` will make num to increment by `1`.

Whereas, in the second example i.e. `while (num < 5)` the loop will terminate when `num -> 5` and `num++` will never be called and hence `num` will be 5 and not 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 1;
while (num++ < 5); 
System.out.println(num);
```

Over here you were `incrementing` value before checking

```
int num = 1;
while (num < 5) num++;
System.out.println(num);
```

Over here you were `incrementing` value after checking

If you're looking for identical loop then you need to do an increment like as `++num` called as `(prefix)` instead of `num++` called as `(postfix)` so your code looks like as

```
int num = 1;
while (++num < 5);
System.out.println(num);
```

Now the above condition is identical to

```
int num = 1;
while (num < 5) num++;
System.out.println(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

In last run of compare loop num++ < 5 will compare first and before breaking the loop add 1 to num. So the result will be 1 higher that the other loop. At last run num will be 5 when the condition will be false. At that point before terminating the loop it'll add 1 i.e. num will become 6 ad then break. While in the other loop it'll not move into the loop and so will not increase to 6.

Answer (score 0):

In your first case System.out.println is out of the while loop body. Because if there is no curly braces then it take single statement as body, means first occurring semicolon is a single statement. In your case it is empty statement

```
;         // is empty statement and valid
```

When it come out of the while loop at that time num=6 and it prints that

Answer (score 0):

**In a simple statement**

```
$num++ < 5  =>>  $num < 5; $num = $num + 1;

++$num < 5  =>>  $num = $num + 1; $num < 5;
```

**AND**

```
while($num < 5) $num++; =>> when (4 < 5)-->> true; --> $num = 5; 
                        =>> when (5 < 5)-->> false;--> $num = 5;;
```